# Reportlab and Fontawesome font

Tags: python, font-awesome, truetype, reportlab

How to use [Fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) with [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/)?
I have some error and don't find any solution

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

pdffile = 'test.pdf'
ttffile = '/somepath/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf'

c = canvas.Canvas(pdffile)
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('fontawesome', ttffile))
c.setFont('fontawesome', 32)
c.drawString(10, 150, "test")
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/somepath/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('fontawesome', ttffile))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 989, in __init__
    self.face = TTFontFace(filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 895, in __init__
    TTFontFile.__init__(self, filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 394, in __init__
    self.extractInfo(charInfo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 469, in extractInfo
    psName = names[6].replace(b" ", b"-")  #Dinu Gherman's fix for font names with spaces
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Reportlab = 3.0

Python = 3.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` from site. Convert `FontAwesome.otf` to `.ttf` using [everythingfonts.com](http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf)

Comment: [convertio.co](https://convertio.co/otf-ttf/) converts bigger files, up to 100Mb. Whereas everythingfonts limits to 0.4Mb for free. Yes strangely the webfont.ttf files that come with the pro version have fewer glyphs than the .otf files.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you have found the answer to your question or solved the problem differently. But I think that this answer can be useful to others. 
You did almost everything right. But FontAwesome is an iconic font. With it, you can not print text. In order to use FontAwesome icons, you must write the Unicode code. 
Here is an example code.

```
# !usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

pdfmetrics.registerFont(
    TTFont("FontAwesome", "fontawesome-webfont.ttf"))
canvas = Canvas("pdffile.pdf", pagesize=letter)
canvas.setFont("FontAwesome", 30)
icon = u"\uf1e3" # fa-futbol-o
canvas.drawString(100,100,icon)
canvas.save()
```

Unicode code is specified on the page of the desired icon or [on this table](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/).